# SQL - using flags vs join queries to fetch relevant records

Tags: sql

Say I have 3 tables:

`reviews  | paid, received_feedback (booleans)

payments | review_id

feedback | review_id`

Would it be worth the performance jump to perform (psuedo-SQL to demonstrate):

`select from reviews where paid = 1`

VS

`select from reviews, joins payments where payments.review_id = reviews.id`

Comment: Do you say you have 2 tables with a 1:N relationship? In the 2nd table you store the payments with a state. Like table1 is "purchase" and table2 is "payment" and each payment has a certain state?

Comment: @hol I've updated to clarify. I have 3 tables: `reviews`, `payments`, `feedback`. My question is would it be worth using flags (reviewed, paid) on the `reviews` table vs performing a join query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm sure there would be a performance jump using flagged columns

You are right: dropping a join usually improves performance

> but is it worth the bother?

This is up to you to decide: if the number of records with which your program must deal is enormous, and you must do it often, then adding flags makes sense. Otherwise, keeping the flags in the correct state would be a continued maintenance liability.

You should also consider the time that your program spends maintaining these flags: if the flags change often, this time may reduce the savings from introducing the flags in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, you've given me something to ponder.